# algorithm to find max group of pairs of a set. But every object in the set can be used max 3 times, and a pair can be used more than once

Tags: python, algorithm

**Explanation**

> I need to find an algorithm to find all pairs of a set.
> Every object in the set can be used maximum 3 times,
> and a pair can be used more than once.

> for example:
> ['a','b','c'] the pairs will be → 'ab','ac','bc', 'ab'.
> I tried to use all the pairs and then to filter them, but it won't work because the pairs can be used more than once

**Code**

```
def fn_pair(start, rest, n):
    if n == 0:
        final_list.append(start)
    else:
        for i in range(len(rest)):
            fn_pair(start + rest[i], rest[i+1:], n-1)
```

Comment: What if the input is `['a']`?

Comment: return False, must return pairs

Comment: How about using the [round-robin algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64604793/get-n-k-unique-sets-of-2-from-list-of-length-n-in-python/64606498#64606498), and going for three rounds?

Answer (score 1):

The max group of pairs of a set: `int(m * n / 2)` or `m * n // 2`

- `m` is the used max times of one object
- `n` is the length of a set

Had test `m` from 2 to 4, `n` from 2 to 9.

In general, about this scenario, here is a simple formula: `int(m * n / p)`, which `p` is the elements of a pair in here is **2**.

Just image that, finding the max groups of pairs of a set in your scenario, the all elements which would be composed the pairs are from the `m` times of `n`(the elements of a set), and divide to the groups dependent on the require elements in a group such a pair is **2**, to get the **whole** groups it should be round down(**integer part**) of the result.

The group list content would be different dependent of the search method.

Here is one of fake code:

```
1, create a dictionary called d which key is the object and the value is m: like d = {'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}
2, create a list for save the pairs, like l
2, start a loop
   remove the value equal to 0 element in d
   if len(d) less than 1, break loop
   if len(d) equal to 1
       - if the element value larger than 1, 
           then generate the pairs as double of key(like 'aa'),
           value subtract 2
           append pairs to l
           continue loop
       - else, break loop
   sorted d by the value from large to small
   generate the pairs from index 0(first key) with others until to the end: like 'ab', 'ac', append to l
   at the same time, the consistent value subtract 1:  d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}
   end a loop
3, output the pairs list l
```

- reference [sorted dictionary by the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)