# Implement a round robin tournament without playing twice with the same partner

Tags: python, graph, round-robin, tournament

I want to organize a badminton tournament in double teams, where no one plays twice with the same partner, using python. I created a graph using nx.Graph and implemented a function to get the list of unplayed partners for each round (each player keeps track of already played partners). But unfortunately, after a few rounds, the algorithm doesn't achieve to find unplayed and available partners (because unplayed partners are already picked in another team). This is my first step, so let's say I have an even number of players.

With that context, how to implement a team matcher which uses a rotation of partners in such a way that everyone plays at each round, and everyone has a different partner ?

Here is my draft of matcher class:

```
import itertools

import networkx as nx


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.previous_partners = set()
        self.score = 0.0

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Team:
    def __init__(self, players: list):
        if len(players) != 2:
            raise ValueError('A team must contain exactly two players')
        self.players = players

    def __str__(self):
        return ' / '.join([str(player) for player in self.players])


class RoundRobinMatcher:

    @staticmethod
    def _create_graph(players: list[Player]) -> nx.Graph:
        graph = nx.Graph()
        for player in players:
            graph.add_node(player, score=player.score)
            for opponent in player.previous_partners:
                graph.add_edge(player, opponent)
        return graph

    @staticmethod
    def _find_unplayed_pairs(graph: nx.Graph) -> list[tuple[Player, Player]]:
        unplayed_pairs = []
        for pair in itertools.combinations(graph.nodes, 2):
            if not graph.has_edge(*pair):
                unplayed_pairs.append(pair)
        return unplayed_pairs

    def match(self, players: list[Player]) -> list[Team]:
        graph = self._create_graph(players)
        unplayed_pairs = self._find_unplayed_pairs(graph)

        teams = []
        for pair in unplayed_pairs:
            for team in teams:
                if pair[0] in team.players or pair[1] in team.players:
                    break
            else:
                teams.append(Team(pair))
        return teams


if __name__ == '__main__':
    players = [Player('a'), Player('b'), Player('c'), Player('d'), Player('e'), Player('f'), Player('g'), Player('h')]
    matcher = RoundRobinMatcher()
    teams = matcher.match(players)
    for team in teams:
        print(team)
```

Comment: If the number of players is n and the number of rounds is at most n-1, then there exists an extremely simple algorithm to assign the players in pairs at every round so that no two players are ever in the same pair. This part doesn't require any graph theory. See for instance [Get n * k unique sets of 2 from list of length n in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64604793/get-n-k-unique-sets-of-2-from-list-of-length-n-in-python/64606498#64606498).

Comment: And then at every round, after having assigned the players in teams of 2 using the round-robin algorithm, you can assign the teams in matches of 2 teams using [networkx.max_weight_matching](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html) to give higher weight to matchings in which every player discovers new opponents

Comment: BTW, when you include code in a question on StackOverflow, it's good practice to make the code into a [mre]. The code you posted cannot be executed, for at least three reasons: because we don't have the `Matcher` class that `RoundRobinMatcher` inherits from, because you didn't write `import networkx as nx`, and because we don't have the `Player` and `Team` classes that you are using in the code. Presumably these classes are not very relevant to the algorithm, so it would be great to rewrite the code in a way that doesn't require these classes.

Comment: I edited the code snippet to be reproducible. Thanks for the links :) I'll have a look